# Microsoft Edge x-ms-format-detection="none"

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

So I have this code

```
<label title={Name} className="label" for={Name}>+000000000000</label>
```

I add the this  into the tag

```
x-ms-format-detection="none"
```

In the End, I have this:

```
<label title={Name} className="label" for={Name} x-ms-format-detection="none">+000000000000</label>
```

I rebuild the solution and the problem is the browser (Edge) doesn't show this prop into element in DOM and still convert a phone number to link.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the problem on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44 version), it can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. If I get any response I will try to provide you in the future. Thanks for your understanding.

As a workaround, please try to add the following `<meta>` tag in the head.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Or, change the `<label>` tag to the `<p>` tag:

```
 <p title={Name} className="label" for={Name} x-ms-format-detection="none">425-882-8080</p>
```

Then, the output as below:

[image]

Comment: Can you offer any explanation or additional resources?

Comment: I changed label tag to p tag and nothing happens Microsoft Edge 44

Comment: What do you mean about nothing happens use the p tag, it still display it as a link? Try to clear the browser cache and cookie, then retest it. If still not working, try to use the meta tag.